# Remembering toggled state of an image and a div using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, toggle

I am a newbie to HTML, CSS and JavaScript and I learned just enough to make a startpage. I have a search bar which toggles between two different search engines when an image element(here it's the logo of the search engine) on the side is clicked and also switches the image element to match the new state. Here's the JavaScript code:

```
function toggleEngine()
{
    var gSearch = document.getElementById("gSearch"); 
    var dSearch = document.getElementById("dSearch");
    
    gSearch.style.display = (
    gSearch.style.display == "none" ? "block" : "none"); 
    dSearch.style.display = (
    dSearch.style.display == "none" ? "block" : "none");

    var logo = document.getElementById("engineLogo").src;

    if (logo.indexOf("google.svg") != -1)
    {
        document.getElementById("engineLogo").src = "icons/duck.svg";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("engineLogo").src = "icons/google.svg";
    }

    document.getElementById("textField").reset();

}
```

HTML code:

```
<html>

<body>
  <div class="search_box">

    <img class="engine" id="engineLogo" src="icons/google.svg" onclick="toggleEngine()" style="cursor:pointer" />

    <div id="gSearch" style="display:block;">
      <form id="textField" class="google" action="https://google.com/search" method="get">
        <input class="input_box" type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search with Google">
        <button class="button"> <img src="icons/search.svg" style="cursor:pointer" /></button>
      </form>
    </div>

    <div id="dSearch" style="display:none;">
      <form class="duck" action="https://duckduckgo.com/" method="get">
        <input class="input_box" type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search with DuckDuckGo">
        <button class="button"> <img src="icons/search.svg" style="cursor:pointer" /></button>
      </form>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The default engine is Google and the alternate is DuckDuckGo. When I refresh the page it always goes back to the default search engine(Google).

How do I make it remember the toggled state? For example: If I've switched to DuckDuckGo, the next time when I open the page the current search engine should be Google. Here's a [live preview](https://dbuxy218.github.io/Prismatic-Night/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) feature of browsers to persist the current-preferred engine.

For example, you can add a `document.onload` function to your script to check the value persisted in browser's `localStorage` and update the logo in the searchbar on the basis of the persisted logo.

```
window.onload = function() {
  var gSearch = document.getElementById("gSearch"); 
  var dSearch = document.getElementById("dSearch");
  
  let storedLogo = localstorage.getItem('preferredEngine');
  let currentLogo;

  // if no value exists in the local storage
  if(!storedLogo){
     currentLogo = document.getElementById("engineLogo").src;
     localStorage.setItem('preferredEngine', currentLogo);
  } else {
    
    // set the logo on the basis of received from local storage
    if(storedLogo.indexOf("google.svg")){
      document.getElementById("engineLogo").src = "icons/google.svg";
      gSearch.style.display = "block";
      dSearch.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("engineLogo").src = "icons/duck.svg";
      dSearch.style.display = "block";
      gSearch.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

And additionally, you can add the following line in the `toggleLogo` method, to update the `localstorage` value with the latest value whenever the user toggles the preferred logo:

```
var logo = document.getElementById("engineLogo").src;
localStorage.setItem('preferredEngine', logo);
```

Comment: No! `preferredEngine` is a key value to store the value of the "preferred engine" selected by the user. You should read up on the reference link that I have attached in the answer. It should help clear things.

Comment: I have updated my answer about updating the `gSearch` and `dSearch` div.

Comment: yeah i realised that it was a key value pair shortly after i wrote the comment. So i deleted it(sorry about that).

Comment: btw where do put the document.onload... . adding it to the script does nothing.

Comment: You should place it in the script itself. I have updated my answer to `window.onload` instead of `document.onload`.

Comment: thnx that worked!! But I had to change the second if statement to `if (storedLogo.indexOf("duck.svg") != -1)` to make it work so plz change it in the answer.